# Spark Tuning - reading small files from S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

we have a usecase where we are using spark to read lot of small files from S3 and experiencing the slowdown errors. what do you think about increasing the below configs to help with s3 slowdowns:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum = 200
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.threads.max = 100
```

the default values for both these are 10 .

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.threads.max` specifies the number of Threads in the AWS transfer manager used for parallelizing S3A operations.

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum` Defines the maximum number of S3A connections

references:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/performance.html - check Options to Tune and DistCP: Parameters to Tune

it mentions:

> We recommend using larger values for processes which perform a lot of
> IO: DistCp, Spark Workers and similar.

Comment: AWS has restrictions on number of S3 read requests per `key`. You can distribute your files into subkeys i.e. `mainkey/key1/file1-1000.csv` then mainkey/key2/file1001-2000.csv` and so on. This way you won't get the slow down errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go for it!

Hadoop 3.4.0 massively increased the defaults. See [Maximizing Performance when working with the S3A Connector](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/performance.html#Options_to_Tune)

This includes 500 connections and 96 threads.

However, if you are being throttled by S3, you will be throttled by S3. Nothing that the s3a connector can do there. Use bigger files.